# Upload app made with android studio version app as update for app inventor created app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have app in google play made from app inventor but i would like to replace the app inventor version into android studio made version. when i upload the .apk to google play it has error because it was a different version. Is there anyone out there have done this successfully?

""""""""
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
""""""""

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact Google Play Developer Support reagarding this issue, a developer can not upload an update that has been signed with a different certificate than the previous version.

If Google is not able to resolve the issue you will have to change the package name of the app and upload it again.